# Не работает sec:authorize

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Хочу скрыть html код.

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
    <li><a href="<c:url value="/request/all-list"/>"><span
    class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span> All requests</a></li>
</sec:authorize>
```

Но оно не работает, как будто роли не загрузились в security.

```
<sec:authorize access="isAnonymous()">

</sec:authorize>
```

Такой код работает, а вот с ролями не хочет.

В модели user реализовал UserDetails

```
@Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Role role : getRoles()){
            result.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getTitle().name()));         
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Попадает 2 роли ADMIN и USER, проверял.

В userService реализовал loadUserByUsername

```
@Transactional
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

User user = userDao.getByUsername(username);

System.err.println(user);
if(user == null){
    throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User with Username: " + username + " not found");

    }
    return user;
}
```

Куда копать/смотреть нужно чтоб spring security увидел роли?

Comment: Попробуйте поменять `<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">` на `<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN')">`

Comment: Использую spring security 4. Пробовал так изначально. Но потом почитал что для 4 версии нужен префикс 'ROLE_'

Comment: Может тогда в `getAuthorities()` добавлять в виде ROLE_ADMIN и ROLE_USER?

Comment: Спасибо огромное помогло, уже планировал переделывать весь код на роли)). Думал что префиксы только в конфигурации используются, а не в базе..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Действительно есть такая особенность поведения Spring Security. У всех ролей должен быть префикс `ROLE_`. [Подробности](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539162/why-does-spring-securitys-rolevoter-need-a-prefix) есть в английском SO.

Попробуйте изменить данные так чтобы в методе `getAuthorities()` имена ролей возвращались с префиксом (ROLE_ADMIN и ROLE_USER).